# Hawtio and Eclipse Virgo Container?

Tags: eclipse-virgo, hawtio

Folks,
I DLd hawtio to play with and I have installed the jolokia-osgi-bundle-1.1.5.jar inside an eclipse Virgo Jetty 3.0.3 container, but when I start hawtio as `http://localhost:8190/hawtio` (I set it to start with that port), I don't see any special tab -- I just see Dashboard, Wiki, JMX, Connect, LOGS, and Maven.

I also tried the jolokia-war-1.1.5.war file, but still see nothing in the tags bar.

I went to connect, and tried LOCAL, saw my Virgo PID, and did the Start Agent, but when I click on the link after the agent was deployed, I see errors about "id:nnnnnnnnn is not a function" and  id:nnnnnnnnn is not a function" LocalDashboardFunction.

Basically,  I don't see ANYTHING pertaining to the virgo repository -- I would have thought I would see a Jetty or perhaps an OSGI tab, but nothing.
Any ideas????

Comment: If I recall on Eclipse Virgo, you need to configure it specially to expose a JMX MBean for OSGi (at least in glashfish I think you had to)

Comment: Thanks Claus for the hint -- I added the jolokia-war-1.1.5.war and the Gemini Management bundle to my local virgo and I now see the OSGI tab.   The next issue I have is that I can't seem to get the REMOTE connections to work.  I added those to a remote virgo, but I don't know the PORT, PATH, USERID/PW (admin/sprinsource)? to use.  Should the port be the JMX port that virgo is configured for??

Comment: Also, since the Virgo I'm using has JETTY in it, why don't I see the Jetty tab showing???

Comment: You need to enable JMX on Jetty also for it to be manageable.

Comment: The remote tab is for connection remotely to other JVMs that has jolokia agent running. The url is for the jolokia agent.

Comment: There is only: host name, port, path, User Name, Password, and a checkbox for PROXY.    I've tried a number of different combinations for port/path (the username/pw is the standard Virgo admin id I presume).  I am using the host name, the JMX port for the container, the path I've tried is "/jolokia" and the id/pw.

Comment: The errors I get are:Cannot Connect: [Exception... "Failure" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:8190/hawtio/lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js?v=1.2.1 :: .send :: line 2" data: no]
Cannot connect to Jolokia to access this Java process

Comment: Is there a way to detail the jolokia PORT in the osgi bundle?